# Errors while upgrading NextJs version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-18

Recently I upgraded my next app from version 12 to version 14.

I did all the required changes using **codemod**.

Now I am continuously getting this following errors:

1. ```
   Unhandled Runtime Error
   Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

   Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <div>.

   See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
   ```
2. ```
   Unhandled Runtime Error
   Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
   ```

I have already solved some errors related to `<div>tag inside <p> tag`. But now I am not able to understand why I am getting the above errors.

I already know the following things:

1. ```
   const XComponent = dynamic(() => import("./XComponent"), { ssr: true });
   ```

   `ssr: false` will not give me the errors but I want my component to render server side.
2. ```
   import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

   export default function App() {
     const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false)

     useEffect(() => {
       setIsClient(true)
     }, [])

     return <h1>{isClient ? 'This is never prerendered' : 'Prerendered'}</h1>
   }
   ```

   cannot use this code as well, again same reason want my component to render server side.

How can I solve this errors with server side redering?

If possible please explain reason.

Looking forward for your help. Thankyou

Comment: As you know, this error occurred due to a mismatch between the pre-rendered React tree from the server and the React tree rendered during the initial browser render. Components cannot be rendered on both the server and client side simultaneously, resulting in different renders. Please provide additional details about the component in question so that I can assist you in addressing this error.